# mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf Null

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5

I'm developing a Laravel application and I'm trying to retrieve fields from a PDF file using mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf but it always return NULL.

```
 public function postPdF(Request $request ){
    $file = $request->file('test');
    $content = fopen($file->getRealPath(),'r');
    $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = \File::extension($name);
    $newName = time().".".$extension;
    Storage::disk("local")->put($newName,$content);
    $pathF =  storage_path('app')."\\".$newName; 

    $pdf = new Pdf($pathF);
    $data = $pdf->getDataFields();

}
```

If I do

```
var_dump($pdf)
```

it returns

```
string(0) ""
```

If I do

```
var_dump($data)
```

it returns

```
bool(false)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: So what are you trying to do with your [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) call? I'd advise sticking with Laravel's ecosystem for this ([Retrieving Files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#retrieving-files))

Comment: In the first part of the code I'm trying to store the pdf file to exclude that it was a path problem.

Answer (score 1):

Receiving false as a return value from getDataFields() is an indication that something failed when executing the command.  A few things to check:

1. Is [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) installed?
2. I had to specify in the options of the Pdf class constructor where the pdftk binary was located.

   ```
   $pdf = new Pdf(
              $pathToPdf, 
              ['command' => $pathToPdfTKBinary]
   );
   ```

   I came across that in the [documentation for shell commmand](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk/blob/master/README.md#shell-command).

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` returns (essentially) a pointer to the file, not the file contents. That means when you're putting `$content` into a file, it's not doing what you're intending.

While you could just replace `fopen` with `file_get_contents`, I'd advise just replacing the following lines...

```
$file = $request->file('test');
$content = fopen($file->getRealPath(),'r');
$name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$extension = \File::extension($name);
$newName = time().".".$extension;
Storage::disk("local")->put($newName,$content);
```

...with something like...

```
$destPath = storage_path('app') . '/' . time() . '.' . $request->test->extension();

Storage::disk('local')
  ->copy($request->test->path(), $destPath);
```

Comment: I changed the lines but it still returns bool(false)